# How do I adjust the signature image on the check via Report Builder 6i?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oraclereports

Is there a slight possibility to do is for me to move manager's signature image up very minimally so it does not touch the outline on the check? Do I have to adjust the signature field in the report or in a dynamic signature image or elsewhere? Please help.

Thanks a lot...

P.S. Unfortunately, I could not copy/paste the sample check, so that you can see what's going on of the signature hitting the border/outline on the check.

Comment: You _may_ be able to adjust the image itself (either reduce the height of the image) or add whitespace to the bottom of it, but that may skew or distort it.  The best bet would be to update the report definition so that the image object falls inside the check layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to fix the problem is to recreate the signature image to make it smaller or to minimize/reduce the image itself via height/length.

Thanks...